# Fitnesse scripts failing when expecting HTTP status code 204 from REST service using Jersey

Tags: rest, fitnesse, jersey-2.0

I am facing an issue while writing fitnesse script to test the response from REST service with error code 204 (No content).

I get the below error while doing so.

```
__EXCEPTION__:com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: POST http://localhost/sample/test returned a response status of 204
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:527) [jersey-client-1.4.jar:1.4]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:505) [jersey-client-1.4.jar:1.4]
```

It seems like the service returns 204 (which is correct) and I expect the same in fitnesse script. Still it gives the exception.

Has anyone faced this kind of issue? If so, do you have any solution for the same?

Comment: are you expecting any content using POST?

Comment: My guess is that if the response is anything other than http response type, POST will not work.

Comment: no. I am not expecting any content in response. And regarding the HTTP response type, we use JAX-RS framework which automatically assigns the HTTP response codes based on the return type of the service.

Example:
Our service method looks like this
`@POST
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
@Consumes({"application/xml","application/json"})
public String restService() {
     // gets the content from an external service
     if(content.isEmpty()){return null};
     return content;
}`

Comment: this will return HTTP status code 204 when we return `null` and 200 when we return the content. The strange thing is, it works fine when we use the service. But this exception occurs only in fitnesse.

Comment: how about the xmlElement part? the answer provided here might be related to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924627/http-204-error-in-rest-web-service-jersey

Comment: What fixture are you using?  Your own custom or an existing one?